# Twill doesn't show forms

Tags: python, twill

I'm trying to login in https://accounts.coursera.org/ using twill for python 
I tried this sheet of code

```
import twill 
b = get_browser()  
b.go("https://accounts.coursera.org/")  
b.showforms()
```

twill doesn't detect the form in the page and showforms methods doesn't show anything !! 
Is that an internal issue in twill package or I'm misssing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import twill 
import webbrowser

b = twill.get_browser()  
b.go("https://accounts.coursera.org/")  
page = b.result.get_page()
tmp_page = "tmp.html"
with file(tmp_page, "w") as f:
    f.write(page)
webbrowser.open(tmp_page)

# b.showforms()
```

I get a page that says..

> Please use a modern browser with JavaScript enabled to use Coursera.

So I suspect that twill doesn't include a javascript interpreter?

Comment: Yep looks like twill doesn't have javascript support
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202446/does-twill-run-javascript-correctly-at-all

Comment: Shame I was getting excited about twill.  There's some javascript implementations in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451619/is-there-a-javascript-ecmascript-implementation-written-in-python one of those might be easy-ish to add.

Comment: ohhh I was excited about this Twill ...I will go back to requests -_-